# What is "r#" in Rust?

Tags: rust

[This page in the guide for rocket](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/requests/) has a piece of code as follows:

```rust
use rocket::form::Form;

#[derive(FromForm)]
struct Task<'r> {
    complete: bool,
    r#type: &'r str,
}

#[post("/todo", data = "<task>")]
fn new(task: Form<Task<'_>>) { /* .. */ }
```

What is the `r#` in the `struct Task`?

I know what a raw string literal is in Rust, which begins with `r` and is immediately bracketed by an arbitrary number of `#`. It seems however in the above snippet of code there is no closing `#`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows you to escape the reserved word `type` and use it as a field of the struct. You can find more about 'raw identifiers' [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/compatibility/raw_identifiers.html).

Comment: Thank you. But a minor correction: your link leads to raw string literal. The concept is called "Raw Identifiers". I think the better link could be here https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/compatibility/raw_identifiers.html

Comment: Rust Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html#raw-identifiers